# How can I change a page's title for each page individually?

Tags: meta-tags

I am wondering if there is a way that I can change the page titles so that users can see a nice title but that at the same time, the internal title of that same page be different?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module that allows you to change it each time or use a different pattern than default Drupal:

[Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)

This module allows you to control a lot more than just the Page title.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the title via a preprocess function in .theme file. For example a theme_preprocess_page function